# awk: add column name with filename in loop

Tags: awk

I have a question to add a column title during a loop with awk:
I currently have this code, which calculates the mean of each line for each csv file :

```
for i in *.csv; do  
  awk -F"," 'NR==1 { next }
        { T=0
           for(N=1; N<=NF; N++) T+=$N;
           T/=NF
           print T }' $i > Mean$i
done
```

So I get files MeanName1.csv, MeanName2.csv, ... containing:

```
2.5                3.5                ...
4.2                3.4
1.2                3.9
1.2                3.7
```

I would like to get a single file "Mean" containing:

```
Name1   Name2   ...
2.5     3.5
4.2     3.4
1.2     3.9
1.2     3.7
```

I failed to use print FILENAME in the loop.

Do you have any suggestions ?
Thank you

Comment: The way you have written the data in the question makes it look like you have several columns of data in the same file. Can we assume that you only have a single column of data per file, as indicated by your actual code?

Comment: Correct, I have only a single column of data in each Mean File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joining the output files is easiest done with `paste`, but I don't think it knows how to add the file names as headers. But we can do that manually to the intermediate output files within the loop, so:

```
for i in *.csv; do
    out="Mean$i"
    echo "${i%.csv}" > "$out"
    awk -F"," 'NR==1 { next }
        { T=0
           for(N=1; N<=NF; N++) T+=$N;
           T/=NF
           print T }' "$i" >> "$out"
done
paste Mean*.csv > All.csv
```

`${i%.csv}` is just the value of `$i` with the suffix `.csv` removed, so for `foo.csv` and `bar.csv`, that gives an output like this:

```
bar     foo
4.33333 2.5
3.8     3.5
```

---

I note you're also skipping the first line of each input line (`NR==1 { next }`). If they contain useful headers, you could of course use those too by changing that to `NR==1 { print; next }` and then removing the `echo` I added above.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks! (I don't need header of each *.csv files, so I keep echo)